# How to get first child tagname of Gridview from javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tagname

This code does not work in Chrome, But it works in IE...
What's wrong??
What is the proper way to get the tagname of firstchild of gridview?

```
idGrid = document.getElementById("GridView1");

function FindTBODY(idGrid)
{
    if(idGrid.firstChild.tagName == "TBODY")
        return(idGrid.firstChild);
    // there is a caption, so go down one more level
    return(idGrid.firstChild.nextSibling);  

} 
    ........

 var oTBODY= FindTBODY(idGrid);
    for(var i=0; ; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            var ctl=oTBODY.childNodes[i].childNodes[0];
            var selectctl = ctl.childNodes[ctl.childNodes.length-1]
            if(selectctl.tagName == "INPUT")
                            {
                               .......
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?  Do you have sample html?

Comment: Are you sure the first child even has a tagname? <hint>textnode</hint>

Comment: <td align="center" valign="top"><input type="image" src="Image/Plus.gif" alt="Select" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1&#39;,&#39;Select$0&#39;);return false;" /></td><td style="width:150px;">0</td><td style="width:150px;">ALL_CLIENTS</td>
  </tr><tr href="Details.aspx?ID=" open="0" hascontent="0">